# {$ne: "", $ne: null } is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I query the clients to get all client that has logo. 
I use this query:

```
 Client.find({logo: {$ne: "", $ne: null }}, { _id: 1, logo: 1 })
```

But I got this results:

```
"clients": [
    {
        "_id": 15,
        "logo": ""
    },
    {
        "_id": 90,
        "logo": "86cd1fa56947629aeee50e5de2cd0a2c.png"
    },
    {
        "_id": 115,
        "logo": ""
    },
    {
        "_id": 189,
        "logo": "add5e6fd2b19d7bd5a5827fb03f114e8.gif"
    }]
```

I don't know why Im still getting "logo": "" from the results. I also tried the equivalent format of the query.

```
 Client.find({ $and: [{ logo: {$ne: null} }, { logo: { $ne: "" } } ]}, { _id: 1, logo: 1 })
```

but still get the same result. Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same property name twice in the same JS object, so `{$ne: "", $ne: null }` becomes `{$ne: null }` as the last occurrence of the property is used.

Instead, you can use the [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#nin) operator to find documents that don't match either of those values:

```
Client.find({logo: {$nin: ["", null]}})
```

Note that I would have expected your `$and` query to have worked, so I'm not sure what happened there.